# Install missing SCCM updates on remote computer using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, installation, updates, sccm

I'm looking for a way to install missing SCCM updates on remote computers using PowerShell.

I came across this function but can't get it to run on a remote computer any ideas?

```
    function Install-MissingUpdate {

    param (
    $computer = "Remote-Computer"
    )
        ([wmiclass]'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK:CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager').InstallUpdates([System.Management.ManagementObject[]] (
         Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM CCM_SoftwareUpdate' -namespace 'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK'))
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code doesn't even take into account the `$Computer` parameter. I've updated the code to use the computer name parameter.

```
function Install-MissingUpdate {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        $ComputerName = "Remote-Computer"
    )
    $UpdateList = [ManagementObject[]](Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Query 'SELECT * FROM CCM_SoftwareUpdate' -Namespace ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK);
    ([wmiclass]"\\$ComputerName\ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK:CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager").InstallUpdates($UpdateList);
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I get this error Exception calling "InstallUpdates" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to cast object of type 
'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' to type 'System.Management.ManagementBaseObject'."
At C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\a916d8a6-2441-4c27-80b8-2fc67d694775.ps1:7 char:5
([wmiclass]"\\$ComputerName\ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK:CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager")

Comment: Looks like you'll have to cast it to a `[ManagementObject[]]`